# Präteritum oder Perfekt in Kinderbüchern?

Tags: tense, perfect-tense, literature, past, preterite

Ich habe den Auftrag, eine Kindergeschichte ins Deutsche zu übersetzen. Der Originaltext ist voller Lautmalereien, die Sprache ist einfach, dem Verlag nach soll das Buch für 3- bis 7-jährige bestimmt sein. Aber es fällt mir schwer, mich zu entscheiden, welche Zeitform kindergerechter ist: Präteritum oder Perfekt?
Einerseits verstehe ich, dass in der Literatur, besonders bei Erzählungen das Präteritum am üblichsten ist. Andererseits, da Geschichten für diese Altersgruppe meistens die gesprochene Sprache widerspiegeln, frage ich mich, ob hier nicht das Perfekt am besten passt und das Präteritum den Kindern eher realitätsfremd wirkt.
Ich habe online Beispiele für beides gefunden, allerdings nur wenige, weil ich vor Ort nur eingeschränkten Zugang zu gedruckten Büchern auf Deutsch habe.
Ich kopiere nachfolgend einen Auszug der Übersetzung (eigentlich vereinzelte Sätze, um die Vergangenheitsform zu priosieren), die ich mit Vorbehalt im Präteritum formuliere, und daneben noch die alternative Version im Perfekt. Könnt ihr mir eure Meinung sagen, welche davon besser klingt?
Einen riesigen Dank im Voraus!

Egal, was die anderen Schafe tun wollten, *sagte Maria dazu immer Ja*. -- Egal, was die anderen Schafe tun wollten, *hat Maria dazu immer Ja gesagt*.
Eines Tages *gingen die Schafe zum Südpol*. -- Eines Tages *sind die Schafe zum Südpol gegangen*.
Die Schafe *erkälteten sich*! -- Die Schafe *haben sich erkältet*!
Die Schafe *bekamen einen Sonnenbrand*. -- Die Schafe *haben einen Sonnenbrand bekommen*.
Ein Schaf *sprang, fiel nicht in den See, fiel auf den Stein, brach sich den Fuß und weinte*: Mäh! -- Ein Schaf *ist gesprungen, nicht in den See gefallen, sondern auf den Stein gefallen, hat sich den Fuß gebrochen und hat geweint: Mäh*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Perfekt steht im Deutschen für die Vergangenheit, wie auch alle anderen Perfekt-Zeitformen. Also ist die Frage nicht Präteritum oder Perfekt, sondern *Präteritum oder Präsens!*

Beides ist möglich. Präsens als Hauptzeitform klingt wirklicher, eignet sich also ganz gut für Bilderbücher oder sehr lebensnahe Handlungen. Präteritum als Hauptzeitform wirkt mehr wie eine Fantasiewelt.

- Falls du Präsens als Hauptzeitform verwendest, und z.B. Bezug auf Vorgänge auf der vorherigen Seite nimmst, stehen diese im Perfekt.
- Falls du Präteritum als Hauptzeitform verwendest, und z.B Bezug auf Vorgänge auf der vorherigen Seite nimmst, stehen diese im Plusquamperfekt.

Auch kleine Kinder kennen schon beides. Präteritum ist das *Märchen-Deutsch* und es ist sicher nicht falsch, ein fantasievolles Buch in dieser Zeitform zu schreiben.

---

Ergänzung: Als Beispiel für das Präsens in fantastischer Literatur [kann man immer Comics anführen.](https://i.weltbild.de/p/valerian-und-veronique-souvenirs-der-zukunft-346258541.jpg?v=1&wp=_max) Aber es gibt umgekehrt auch Comics, [die im Präterium erzählt werden.](https://comix-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Digedags_Amerika_139.jpg)

Comment: Nicht eher "Präteritum oder Präsensperfekt"? ...

Comment: Nein. Das Haupttempus ist niemals das Perfekt, denn alle Perfekttempora zeigen die Vergangenheit im Bezug auf das Haupttempus an.

Comment: Ich verstehe den ersten Absatz nicht Das Präteritum steht doch im Deutschen auch für die Vergangenheit. Wieso scheidet dann das Perfekt aufgrund dieser Eigenschaft aus, das Präteritum aber nicht?

Comment: Das Präteritum ist das Erzähltempus. Es steht für den Moment der Geschichte, der gerade erzählt wird. Wenn deine Geschichte in der Vergangenheit spielt, kannst du damit natürlich Vergangenes ausdrücken. Aber die Geschichte kann genausogut auch in der Gegenwart oder Zukunft spielen, oder in einer Fantasiewelt und dennoch verwendet man Präteritum. Das Präteritum legt keine Zeitinformation gegenüber der Gegenwart der Wirklichkeit fest. Es ist von der Wirklichkeit abgekoppelt.

Answer (score 4):

Lesen und fiktionale Geschichten sind eine Welt, in die man Kinder mit den ersten Büchern, die man ihnen vorliest, einführt, auch in der Hoffnung, dass sie sich in dieser Welt wohlfühlen und dann auch selber gern lesen. An das Hören und Verstehen von Geschichten muss sich ein Kind ja auch erstmal gewöhnen und baut dabei beim Zuhören Sprachkompetenz auf. Es lernt, was eine Geschichte überhaupt ist, wie fiktionale Texte funktionieren, und dass das etwas anderes ist, als wenn jemand erzählt, was heute auf dem Weg zum Kindergarten passiert ist.

Daher fände ich es falsch, anfangs das Perfekt und damit eine unübliche Zeitform für Geschichten zu benutzen. Das würde nur bedeuten, dass die üblichen Erzählzeitformen Präteritum und Präsens dem Kind länger fremd bleiben. Eine kindgerechte Sprache schließt m.E. Präteritum und Präsens ein, das ist keine Überforderung.

Comment: Was für Kinder ungewohnt ist, ist regional unterschiedlich. Wie in https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73673/will-i-sound-weird-if-i-consistently-use-pr%C3%A4teritum erst kürzlich diskutiert, hört man in Süddeutschland kein Präterium in der Umgangssprache. Weiter nördlich ist es dann eher umgekehrt. Ich habe zwar lange nichts mit kleinen Kindern zu tun gehabt, aber ich denke, die sind da flexibel. Eine Überforderung würde ich da nicht gleich sehen. Erzählteile sind wohl richtig im Präterium. Kinderdialoge im Präterium klingen allerdings in Süddeutschland gestelzt.

Comment: @UweGeuder Auch im Norden wird das Präteritum in der Umgangsprache nur wenig bzw. hauptsächlich für Hilfsverben eingesetzt, "Gestern schien die Sonne." sagt man im Norden umgangssprachlich auch eher nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Das Perfekt scheidet schon allein aus Stilgründen aus. Da bei dieser Zeitform jeder Satz entweder mit »sein« oder mit »haben« gebildet wird, würde es zu ständigen Wiederholungen dieser beiden Hilfsverben kommen.

Comment: Genau, auch wenn es um Reime geht, wirken all die "haben" und "sein" echt unangenehm.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe keinerlei diesbezügliche Qualifikation, aber für mich hört sich Präteritum viel besser an.

Und im ersten Beispiel halte ich, jedenfalls ohne Kontext, "Maria sagte dazu immer Ja" für die bessere Satzstellung.