# Why does "und" in this phrase start a Nebensatz?

Tags: subordinate-clause

In the phrase:

*Meine Großmutter erzählt, dass er dauernd in seiner Werkstatt saß und an seinen elektronischen Geräten gebastelt hat*

why does und create a NS with the verb, *gebastelt hat*, at the end?

Comment: It doesn't start it. It continues the subclause started by "dass".

Comment: "und" connects two pieces of "equal kind". We have a Nebensatz to the left and one to the right, with implciit "dass" as a conjunction. If I wanted to put a Hauptsatz to the right of the "und", I would place a comma in front of the "und" to emphasize that I don't want to implicitly connect to the left Nebensatz, for instance: ".... Werkstatt saß, und er hat an seinen Geräten gebastelt". However, in this sentence I would consider conjunctive, because we have reported speech; however this is a different issue, not related to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The structure is A dass (B und C). So "dass" introduces the entire clause "er dauernd in seiner Werkstatt saß und an seinen elektronischen Geräten gebastelt hat", which in turn is made of two clauses "er dauernd in seiner Werkstatt saß" and "an seinen elektronischen Geräten gebastelt hat". It's a bit unusual because normally "und" joins main clauses. But in this case they are two subordinate clauses, so both have the verb in last position.

PS. It seems odd that you'd combine preterite "saß" with perfect "gebastelt hat" in the same sentence. I'm not sure what the policy on mixing tenses is in German, but in English it would be frowned upon.

Comment: Side note on "preterite" + "perfect": In German that doesn't really matter. You can use both "bastelte" and "gebastelt hat" in the sentence.

Comment: @Em1 You can, but it still has a slightly different meaning. If both happen at the same time, they should be in the same tense, which ist the case here.

Comment: There is a tendency (especially in northern) variants of German to avoid the perfect forms of certain verbs (and use the preterite instead). This rule is almost universally applied for "sein", but other often occuring, typically short, strong verbs are also affected. "... gesessen hat" would sound less natural to me (as a native speaker from a larger city in central-eastern Germany).

Comment: See the discussion in the comments on this answer: <https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73673/will-i-sound-weird-if-i-consistently-use-pr%c3%a4teritum/73677#73677>

Comment: > It seems odd that you'd combine preterite "saß" with perfect "gebastelt hat"
As a native speaker, I disagree. Not doing it that way would be unidiomatic for most Germans. If you simply say "er saß in seiner Werkstatt", the idiomatic tense for the follow up question would be "und was hat er dort gemacht?", to which the answer would be "er hat gebastelt". Constructing the single sentence in the same way is absolutely idiomatic and more so than a construction with "saß und bastelte". For some reason, that just *sounds* wrong.

Comment: More accurately, there is just one subordinate clause, which consists of a subject (_er_) and two coordinated predicates or verb phrases (_dauernd in seiner Werkstatt saß_ and _an seinen elektronischen Geräten gebastelt hat_). As the base conjunctive coordinator, _und_ does not normally join just main clauses, but _any_ two elements that need joining conjunctively – noun phrases (subjects, objects, etc.), predicates, prepositional phrases, adverbs, etc. There’s nothing strange or unusual about its use here.

Answer (score -2):

On the surface, it is the conjunction of two equivalent sentences without repeting the subject

> dass er dauernd in seiner Werkstatt saß *und* [dass er] an seinen elektronischen Geräten gebastelt hat

The implication, that tinkering happened in the garage, follows pragmatically. Part of the problem may be that the Germanic preterite derives from Proto-Indo-European imperfect with perfective and passive connotation, close to a participle, which may be omitted: *... dass er in seiner Garage [sitz-end / gesessen] an elektronischen Geräten gebastelt hat.* Tempus, mood, and aspect are not the focus of the question, however.

One may wonder if there's more *structure* to this specific use of the conjunction. I'll respond in German.

---

Das ist offensichtlich eine Form des W-Fragewortes als Relativpronomen in Konjunktivgebrauch mit Syllabifiziierung

- **k<sup>w</sup>* >> *w* ><sup>?</sup> *u*

Die Endung wie in lateinisch *quando* ("wann") ist in letzter Instaz vermutlich aus *... und da*, *und dann* o.ä. ausgebrochen. Die Beispiele schnitz ich mir fix aus den Rippen.

> Man saß in der Werkstatt, *wo* an elektronischen Geräten gebastelt wurde.

> * Man ging in die Werkstatt *und* an elektronischen Gerät gebastelt wurde.

Die Entsprechung ist offensichtlich nicht einfach richtig. Eine umfassende Untersuchung liegt mir auch nicht vor. Es bedarf der Erklärung. Andere Möglichkeiten bleiben offen. Partikel sind ohnehin schwierig, siehe insbesonder romänisch *și* "und" < lat. *sic* (en.WT), Ableitung von *si* "wenn, falls; wenn doch, ob" (de.WT), vgl. de. *so, so dass, so denn* etc.

Immerhin wird Lat. *quando* als Zusammenziehung aus *quam* (“wie”) +‎ instrumental **dō* rekonstruiert, wobei Lat. *de* regulär hochdeutsch *zu* entspricht. Dementsprechend findet sich die Redewendung

> "wie wennze [*sic!*] träumst"

Oft wird *wenn'ze* geschrieben und zwar auf Autoaufklebern. Der Leser geht wegen der Konjugierung von Analogie mit *du* aus, "[Auto] fahren ist wie wenn du fliegst". Dafür ist zweckmäßig ein Einfluss verblichener s-Pronomina anzunehmen, vgl. heute *Sie*, »Is gutes Geld drin, wennze sich so 'ne Nummern zutraun und da nich bei draufgehn.« (F. Scott Fitzgerald, *Winterträume*, Übersetzter nicht genannt). Bemerkenswert ist unterdessen die Konjunktion *so*, *... so sie sich so etwas zutraurn*.

Dieses Sandhi ist sicherlich nicht ursprachlich mit *quando* gleichzusetzen, dennoch bemerkenswert. In diesem Sinne ist ein Übergang zur dritten Person jedenfalls leicht vorstellbar.

> ... er dauernd in seiner Werkstatt saß *und* [er] an seinem Gerät gebastelt hat

> ... er dauernd in die Werkstatt ging, *wenn* er an seinem Gerät gebastelt hat

Das klitische Pronomen mag deswegen unbetont sein, mundartlich "wenna ma widda" o.ä. Das erklärt jedoch kaum *'ze* für *du*. Da muss also mehr dahinter stecken.

Daneben besteht auch Lat. *unde*, welches ungefähr engl. *whence* übersetzt, s. OE *hwanon* noch ohne *-s*, d.i. Dativus Locativus oder adverbialer Genetiv? Ist erstmal auch egal. Vgl. *Wo-her soll ich das wissen*. S. a. **ut* als entsprechende Antwort zu ablativ *woher?* — *Aus'n Norden*. Das dürfte Bedeuten, dass der Vokal schon gemeingermanisch eintrat, falls man gewillt ist, einen Bezug zu **k<sup>w</sup>* darin zu suchen. Im Latein wird *rebracketing* wie *ne-qubi, nec-ubi* vermutet; †*qubi* liegt aber nicht vor und deutet meines erachtens auf ursprünchliches ***u̯*.

An dieser Stelle kann ferner auf *-hw* ("und") verwiesen werden, wo das doch zumindest in Gotisch die Entsprechung zu Lat. *-que* u.s.w. ("und") darstellt, das aber immer als Nachsilbe auftritt. Unterdessen ist *und*, das im Gotischen fehlt, zu lat. *ante* zu vergleichen. Dieser Ansatz bleibt hier unberührt.

Vergleichbar wäre bei *quam* auch der Vokalismus zu *um*.

> ... er dauernd in seiner Werkstatt saß ***um*** [*sich?*] an seinem Gerät ***zu*** basteln

Bemerkenswert ist einerseits das zu-Partizip (vgl. oben *'ze*). Andererseits wird *um* < *umbi* mit Lat. *ambi* verglichen, das nicht als Konjunktion eignet. Grimm (DWB: *um*) stellt fest: "*causales* um *ist ahd. häufig bezeugt, seltener im ags. und as.*", bspw. "halt mich umbe dina gnada (*salvum me fac propter misericordiam tuam*) 2, 15, 13;", insb. "umpi daz"; die "infinitivconstruction" mit *um — zu* ist ab 13. Jh. nachweisbar (so Grimm).

---

So viel dazu. Ausgangspunkt dieser Betrachtung ist die Annahme, mit lat. *quando* müsste ein Relativpronomen als Konjuntion verständlich werden, etwa *wo, wenn, wann*. Das Verwechslungspotential zeigt sich unter anderem in englisch *when* (OE *hwonne* "wann") und *whence* (OE *hwanon* "woher"), lateinisch *ne-cubi*, *nec-ubi*, außerdem slavisch *die Oder* (wohl zu *Wasser*). Ansonsten sind kaum Beisoiele für einen Initialen Wechsel *w-* / *u-* zu finden. Eventuel ist unter den Appelativen noch *Uodal* zu altsächsisch *Odal* mit *Edel-*, *Adel* zu verbinden (Unknown," en.WT: PGem **aþalą*) und behelfsweise **ḱweytós* anzusetzen, vgl. *weiß* < **ḱweydós*, walisisch *gwyn* "weiß", griechisch ειδοσ usw. < **weyd-*.

Demgegenüber ist *und* aus der Nullstufe abzuleiten, genauso wie *un-*. Dasselbe Prinzip dürfte auch für *k<sup>w</sup>* zum Ziel führen.